# repl in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scheme, read-eval-print-loop

I'm making a simple Scheme interpreter in JavaScript. Everything is working fine but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a repl. The way I want it to work is the when the user is selected inside the textarea, the cursor becomes disabled. I don't want the user to use the mouse or arrow keys to insert the cursor in the middle of the current line they are typing. This way I can add every key pressed on a stack (or pop it), and when the user hits enter, the interpreter parses and evaluates the line and returns the output on the next line.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: I suggest listening `keyup` jquery event on some `div` or `body` & then append key to that div or body using `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);`

Comment: The way I did it was add an event listener on a textarea that waits for a keydown event. Then I append the event.key to a stack (or pop it off if it's a backspace). The problem is how to prevent a user form moving the cursor around.

Comment: As we are using `textarea` here, user will anyway able to move cursor either by `arrow` or by mouse. There is no way to prevent this, but if we listen `keydown` on div & give some textarea looking css to it then it allows repl without cursor problem, yet look like normal textarea

Comment: also, check out http://tryclj.com -- might give you some inspiration